# Why Form1.resx dont allow me to Edit/Add resources?

Tags: c#, winforms

I add one Windows Form name as `Form1.cs` in my project and try to edit local resource file of same `Form1.cs` ( `Form1.resx` ) file, while editing VS pop up following confirmation box:

[image]

I don't understand why VS restrict me to add local resource file of `Form1.cs`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The form resource files (like Form1.resx) are serialized by VisualStudio. For this reason all manually added resources will be removed during design-time serialization. You should only edit resources in the resx file, which have already been added by the design time. Adding resources directly into the resx file will result in their deletion next time the form is changed (and has been subsequently serialized).

Solution:

Store all manually defined strings (or custom resources) in the application resources. By default, this file is Resources.resx and is located in the Properties folder in your application.

Source : http://www.telerik.com/support/kb/winforms/general/resources-in-form-s-resx-files-are-lost.aspx

Comment: What is "serialized by VisualStudio"?

Comment: All the controls, strings, images will be serialized or converted to XML file and which is saved with the form, if you add / edit any control VS will re-create it